# Socket.io different pages for different ports

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have this socket.io:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

let http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(http);

let http2 = require('http').Server(app);
let io2 = require('socket.io')(http2);


io.on('connect', function(socket) {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/one_dir'));
});

io2.on('connect', function(socket) {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/another_dir'));
});

http.listen(4000, function(){
   console.log('check *:4000');
});

http2.listen(5000, function () {
   console.log('& check *:5000');
});
```

I am new in node.js(and in socket too), so I need that on 127.0.0.1:4000 was index.html from **/one_dir**, and on 127.0.0.1:5000 was index.html from **/another_dir**, 
Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: First off, there's almost no reason to use two separate socket.io servers since you can typically just use separate messages from separate pages and your code can handle things different for each page that way

Comment: Second, your question does not include client-side code or include what your problem actually is that you want help with.  What did you try?  And, what was the problem you had with that?

Comment: Third, you should NEVER put an `app.use()` statement inside a `connect` event.  That will just install that middleware multiple times (which probably won't do any harm other than waste memory), because it is certainly not doing what you want and is not the correct way to install middleware.  You can't install different middleware on your Express server for different users.  Middleware is installed for all users who make requests to that server.

Comment: Probably what you should do is back way up and describe what you're really trying to achieve with your design and we might then be able to suggest an appropriate design.